Adding the value at the end of the array within the loop
I have tried appending the value at the end of the array.
<cfset NL = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.System").getProperty("line.separator")>
<cfset MyList= listToArray(UpldRslt,NL,false,true)>

<cfloop from="2" to="#ArrayLen(MyList)#" index="i">
  <cftry>
    <cfoutput>
      <cfset FinalList = reMatch('(?:"(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*)', MyList[i])>

      <cfset ResidentialIndicatorOverrideID = replace(FinalList[1], """", "", "ALL") >
      <cfset Address = replace(FinalList[2], """", "", "ALL") >
      <cfset City = replace(FinalList[3], """", "", "ALL") >
      <cfset State = replace(FinalList[4], """", "", "ALL") >
      <cfset Zipcode = replace(FinalList[5], """", "", "ALL") >
      <cfif IsNumeric(Zip) eq "NO">
        <cfset ErrorNote = "Please enter the numeric value for ZIP" >
        <cfset ErrorOccured= 1> 
      </cfif>
      <cfif ErrorOccured eq 1>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(Mylist[i],"#ErrorNote#","true")>
      </cfif>
</cfloop>

If i use <cfset ArrayAppend(Mylist,"#ErrorNote#","true")> it is appending the value
the o/p for above line is
test,2,3,4,5
6,2,3,7,8
Please enter the numeric value for ZIP

The o/p which i am expecting is
test,2,3,4,5,Please enter the numeric value for ZIP
6,2,3,7,8

Some mistake in Arrayappend. Please help me with this

You should use ListAppend instead of ArrayAppend as Mylist elements are string values.

Please post the code with the data returned as hardcoded data. No way for us to guess what is in there.
